# Max and min in OPP in Racket

Tags: racket

I am stuck on one problem in my programming homework in my Intro to Computer Science class. We had to use OPP in Racket to create a car% and then use object to creat my-car. We also had to create a function accelerate to make the my-car accelerate by 10 each time the function is called and brake, which will brake the car by 7 each time it is called. BUT we have to set a minimum speed of 0 and a max of 65, so my-car does not go under 0 no matter how many times we call brake, and it does not go over 65 no matter how many times we call accelerate. Any advice as to how to do this?
I tried:
(define/public set-current-speed)
   (range 0 65)
BUT that did not work. I have never worked with ranges or min/max values so I am just stuck. Any advice would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance.

```
(require racket)

(define auto%
  (class object%
    (field
     (color "?")
     (brand "?")
     (model "?")
     (year 1900)
     (current-speed 0)
     )
    (super-new)
    (define/public (get-color)
      color
    )
    (define/public (set-color new-color)
      (set! color new-color)
    )
    (define/public (set-brand given-brand)
      (set! brand given-brand)
    )
    (define/public (set-model given-model)
      (set! model given-model)
    )
    (define/public (set-year given-year)
      (set! year given-year)
      )
    (define/public (get-info)
      (string-append color " " (number->string year) " " brand " " model " ")
    )
    (define/public (get-current-speed)
      current-speed
    )
      )
    (define/public (accelerate)
      (set! current-speed (+ current-speed 10))
      )
    (define/public (brake)
      (set! current-speed (- current-speed 7))
      )
    )
  )
```

Comment: So, the `accelerate` procedure adds 10 to the `current-speed` _no matter what that speed is?_ The `brake` procedure subtracts 7 from `current-speed` _no matter what the current speed is?_

Comment: Yes. I think that I figured it out. I added the following to the accelerate function:           ```(if (>= current-speed 56) 65``` and ```(if (<= current-speed 7) 0``` to the brake function. It  kind of works. It returns two values if the value is over or under but I will keep working.

Comment: What's "OPP"? Is it the same as "object-oriented programming" (OOP)?

Comment: The `max` and `min` functions are your friends: `(min 70 65)` is `65` for instance.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would use `let` to bind the speed after acceleration to `new-speed`, and then check whether `new-speed` had exceeded the speed-limit. If so, simply `set!` the `current-speed` to the speed-limit, otherwise set it to `new-speed`. A similar approach will work for decelerating.

```
(define current-speed 50)

(define (accelerate)
  (let ((new-speed (+ current-speed 10)))
    (if (> new-speed 65)
        (set! current-speed 65)
        (set! current-speed new-speed))))
```

```
scratch.rkt> current-speed
50
scratch.rkt> (accelerate)
scratch.rkt> current-speed
60
scratch.rkt> (accelerate)
scratch.rkt> current-speed
65
scratch.rkt> (accelerate)
scratch.rkt> current-speed
65
```